In java eclipse, the error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException:. Give alternative answer for this error?
The error displays with:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for E:\selenium-java-4.21.0\byte-buddy-1.14.15-sources.jar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: byte.buddy: Invalid module name: 'byte' is not a Java identifier

I am not getting proper solution for this error.
I added external jar files with selenium-java-4.21.0 in class path libraries. After that, the error was still there and at last I tried to add same external jar in module path. But the error remains same. I was expecting to get proper alternative solutions of this error and also expecting to get proper chrome driver file

Does deleting your module-info.java file fix your issue (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and Configure)? You might also need to delete your run configuration in Run > Run Configurations....

No it is not able to fix my issue. In console it displayed as jar files are not read and this things happen many times.

In Project > Properties: Java Build Path, tab Libraries, move byte-buddy-1.14.15-sources.jar from the Modulepath to the Classpath (assuming it's not a Maven project and that you have deleted your module-info.java file; if it's a Maven project you need right-click the project and choose Maven > Update Projects... after you deleted your module-info.java file). If this all does not help, please show your .classpath file and if it's a Maven, Gradle, etc. project, your build file.
